# Json response to class mapping Restsharp deserializing

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, deserialization, restsharp

I am using RestSharp to consume a restful webservice. I am using the built in Json Deserializer to deserialize the response.
This is the response.

```
[{"id":"1","latitude":"18.0155848","longitude":"-77.4988293","rating":"1","streetid":"1","username":"joel","verified":"1"},{"id":"2","latitude":"18.0155892","longitude":"-77.498774","rating":"1","streetid":"2","username":"joel","verified":"0"},{"id":"3","latitude":"18.0227736","longitude":"-77.4980039","rating":"1","streetid":"3","username":"joel","verified":"0"}]
```

These are the models its being mapped to.

```
List<Pothole> list = new List<Pothole>();

 public class Pothole
 {
    //getters and setters for the attributes of Pothole Model
    public long Id { get; set;}
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double Rating{ get;set;}
    public long StreetId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public bool Verified { get; set; }
}
```

However when I make the call the data is not being deserialized.I am wondering if there is a problem with the json response to the class mapping. I am mapping the response to a list of potholes due to an array of pothole objects being returned. I check the HTTP status code and the content of the response so the data is being returned, its just the deserializing causing a problem.

Comment: I'm guessing you have an issue with the difference in case between the JSON and the class you're mapping to...

Comment: @PaulSasik Yes thats what I am having a problem with.

Comment: are the models/classes accurate?

Comment: You need to match the case of the JSON variables. id instead of Id etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Pothole
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string latitude { get; set; }
    public string longitude { get; set; }
    public string rating { get; set; }
    public string streetid { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string verified { get; set; }
}
```

C# is case sensitive and so the reflection that takes place in populating the C# object will look for properties with names EXACTLY like those in the JSON string.

Also, if you're using Visual Studio 2012 SP 1 you can actually paste JSON text as a C# class. Pretty handy.

Comment: RestSharp is case insensitive i.e. it will deserialize regardless of the case, that is its biggest advantage.

Comment: Is there anyway to specify how it deserializes? I don't want to follow the lowercase convention of JSON in my C# object.

Comment: @Nick: Are you asking Toni or me? `If me:` no, not in the current flavor, `if Toni:` Take a look at the RestSharp lib to see if it's configurable

Answer (score 1):

Or you can also use : [Json2Csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)

```
generate c# classes from json
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but I thought I'd throw in my $0.02.  I am using an unmodified version of RestSharp.Portable 1.6.2 Xamarin PCL

I have json as follows:

```
{"blah":{"iPAddress":"10.1.1.x","cPU":"1 vCPU","dNSName":"blah.blah.com"}}
```

with the class below, the deserialzation does not work for CPU, works for DSName, and IPAddress though.

```
public class Blah
{
    public string CPU { get; set; }
    public string DNSName { get; set; }
    public string IPAddress { get; set; }
}
```

However if I change CPU to cPU it works fine.

```
public class Blah
{
    public string cPU { get; set; }
    public string DNSName { get; set; }
    public string IPAddress { get; set; }
}
```

So, feels like a bug, just wanted to contribute.

Comment: I would expect you need the correct case for all your properties, not just cPU ?